# GitPython to pull a specific directory

Tags: python, git, gitpython

To pull a specific directory in the remote using git I would do:

```
> git fetch <remote> <branch>
> git checkout <remote>/<branch> -- relative/path/to/file/or/dir
```

How do I do the same using GitPython?  I'm trying to figure it out but no cigar so far.  I'm currently playing with something like the below, but i'm just getting errors.  I'm clearly not using the git python api correctly.

```
repo = git.Repo.init("local\repo\path")
devRemote = repo.create_remote(\
    "Dev", "http:\\devremote.git")
repo.create_head('master', devRemote.refs.master)
repo.heads.master.set_tracking_branch(devRemote.refs.master)
devOrigin.fetch()
repo.heads.master.checkout("TargetDir/")
```

Comment: That's not how git was designed. You have to check out a full revision, unless of cause your folder is a submodule.

Comment: @KlausD. ?  Can you clarify, the `git` code I posted, works for sure.  Do you mean to say `GitPython` won't do that?

Comment: Hey did you figure this  out?